# Generating unique index for unique content column on select

Tags: mysql

I want to generate an additional column on a select statement that will generate a unique sequential number for unique content.  For example for the table that follows I might want to ad an Ad-Hoc index into the  selected output on country.

I don't want this index built into the table, the objective is to have, any query able to assign a unique number to any column of unique content.  See Below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `phone`;

CREATE TABLE `phone` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `area` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `number` DECIMAL(8,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `extension` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (44, 9876, 54321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (22, 9873, 64321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (22, 9874, 64321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (33, 9875, 64321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (33, 9877, 64321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (55, 9878, 64321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (55, 9879, 64321, 42);
INSERT INTO `phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`) VALUES (55, 9870, 64321, 42);

select '~Magic_Happens_Here~' , country,area,number from phone
order by country;
```

with IDEALLY, the output as follows..

```
~Magic_Happens_Here~    country area    number
1                       22      9873    64321
1                       22      9874    64321
2                       33      9875    64321
2                       33      9877    64321
3                       44      9876    54321
4                       55      9870    64321
4                       55      9878    64321
4                       55      9879    64321
```

The reason for this is to facilitate post select presentation.  The important thing is to be able to do this in the select, not build it into the table, because the queries will be ad-hoc, and the decision will be made at the time of the select, which content to number uniquely.

I tried searching on this, but maybe I am missing the correct terminology, I drew a blank on this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer I was looking for was the RANK function, which MySQL does not support directly, so the way  to do this is as follows.

```
select FIND_IN_SET(country, @values_set) as rank,
country, area,number from phone, 
(SELECT @values_set := GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT country
ORDER BY country);
```